# Adding JQuery "Read More" Script Without Stripping HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm applying a "Read More" link script to a Rich HTML field so that longer blocks of copy are truncated. Below is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxLength = 300;
    $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
        var myStr = $(this).text();
        if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
            var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
            var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
            $(this).empty().html(newStr);
            $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
            $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
        }
    });
    $(".read-more").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

In my template, I have the field flowing into a div with the show-read-more class applied, and it works fairly well.

Example usage follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Add Read More Link</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var maxLength = 300;
      $(".show-read-more").each(function() {
        var myStr = $(this).text();
        if ($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength) {
          var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
          var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
          $(this).empty().html(newStr);
          $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
          $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
        }
      });
      $(".read-more").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .show-read-more .more-text {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="show-read-more">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a very long paragraph...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce efficitur massa id odio pharetra, in varius diam tincidunt. Nulla fringilla nunc lorem. In et elit id diam porttitor finibus vitae ut odio. Morbi sollicitudin
      turpis non vulputate efficitur. Nulla rhoncus metus diam, porta consequat lacus scelerisque sed. Praesent et tempor mauris, non porttitor sapien. Pellentesque placerat ex non finibus gravida. Aenean at feugiat odio, sit amet ultricies diam. Integer
      vehicula pulvinar leo, vel laoreet neque lacinia nec. Vestibulum nec cursus orci, vel dapibus risus. Nullam et tincidunt mauris. Nunc iaculis egestas purus in rhoncus. Donec a turpis quis libero rutrum.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that the code is stripping out all of the HTML tags, making it all one big unformatted paragraph. How can I achieve the same thing without striping out the HTML?

Comment: I feel like this entire thing can be done much easier with some css and using js to add/remove class only

Comment: Also please add the relevant html and css to create a minimal executable example, that way people can debug with the code and solve it faster

Comment: I agree with @Huangism, CSS might be a simpler approach. I was trying to do the same thing with javascript a few months ago and followed this instead, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/. For me, it's been easier to maintain/tweak (if needed) and use in other projects.

Comment: I need it to be a JS solutions for multiple reasons. One, it needs to be dynamic, only applying if the content exceeds a certain length. Two, I need it to generate the link in such a way that I can also add a google event and track in the analytics who actually reads the whole thing.

Comment: Why not css overflow hidden and visible? It is possible to do it with substrings, but it is a lot more complicated.

Comment: You can generate the link with js like you are doing, the part where you have the `...` can be done with css. Your js will just add the link when needed and toggle a class on the element to show/hide the text

Answer (score 0):

Using .text() will grab only the text and strip tags, if you are looking to grab all child elements and put that into a variable use .html();

```
var myStr = $(this).html();
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/h9g8znyp/1/)

Comment: Think about what happens when there is a html tag where the dots starts

Comment: That solved the tag-stripping issue, but now it's adding a closing P tag which creates an awkward split in the copy.